# Combobox not showing correct number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel (365) spreadsheet with two Comboboxes - Combobox1 and Combobox2 both are used to list the same data for different purposes on different tabs. My problem is that although I have changed listrows in both to the same number (20) only Combobox2 shows 20 rows. Combobox1 only shows the previous number of rows (15) although set to display 20. Anyone know how to get it to behave properly?

EDIT I have solved my origional problem but I would however be interested in using VBA to automatically update both listfillrange and listrows when a new row of data is added. I do have a macro that I use to add new data to my data table that could be adapted to also update listfillrange and listrows

```
Sub add_to_table_sa_3()
'Written by Keith Cooper 27/10/2021
Dim NewRow As Integer
NewRow = Worksheets("input").Range("E1").Value + 1
If Worksheets("input").Range("F1").Value <> 0 Then
MsgBox "There are errors. No data has been added!", vbOKOnly, "Warning!"
Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B3").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B4").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B5").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B6").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B7").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B8").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 7).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B9").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 8).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B10").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 9).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B11").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 10).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B12").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 11).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B13").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 12).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B14").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 13).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B15").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 14).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B16").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 15).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B17").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 16).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B18").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 17).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B19").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 18).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B20").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 19).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B21").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 20).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B22").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 21).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B23").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 22).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B24").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 23).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B25").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 24).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B26").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 25).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B27").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 26).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B28").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 27).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B29").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 28).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B30").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 29).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B31").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 30).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B32").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 31).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B33").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 32).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B34").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 33).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B35").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 34).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B36").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 35).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B37").Value
'Range("B38") is a heading
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 36).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B39").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 37).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B40").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 38).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B41").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 39).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B42").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 40).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B43").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 41).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B44").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 42).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B45").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 43).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B46").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 44).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B47").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 45).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B48").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 46).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B49").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 47).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B50").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 48).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B51").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 49).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B52").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 50).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B53").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 51).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B54").Value
Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 52).Value = Worksheets("input").Range("B55").Value

Sheets("Input").Select
           Range("C2").Value = "Data added"
           MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly, "Transfer Data"
           
Worksheets("input").Range("E1").Value = NewRow
Worksheets("input").Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: How and where do you set `listrows` ? Manually in Excel or via Code (you tagged your question with VBA). If via Code: Show your code. If no: Remove the tag.

Comment: A possible solution could have been with VBA, however I have now solved the problem, the problem was a difference in the listfillrange value. Thanks anyway

Comment: I cannot follow your original question (apparently it is now solved?) as I see no combobox or how your setting it, plus you've changed the question now, and I still don't see `listfillrange` or `listrows`.  Please review the guidelines for asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the 52 lines transposing the data with one line inside a For/Next loop

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub add_to_table_sa_3()
    Dim NewRow As Long, i as Long, arData
    
    With Sheets("Input")
        If .Range("F1").Value <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are errors. No data has been added!", vbOKOnly, "Warning!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        arData = .Range("B3:B55").Value
        NewRow = .Range("E1").Value + 1
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Data") 

        For i = 1 To 35 
            .Cells(NewRow, i) = arData(i, 1) 
        Next 
        'Range("B38") is a heading 
        For i = 37 To 65
           .Cells(NewRow, i - 1) = arData(i, 1) 
        Next 
        'Range("B68") is a heading 
        For i = 67 To UBound(arData) 
            .Cells(NewRow, i - 2) = arData(i, 1) 
        Next 
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "'" & .Name & "'!A2:A" & NewRow 
        Sheet6.ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "'" & .Name & "'!A2:A" & NewRow 

    End With
    
    With Sheets("Input")
        .Range("C2").Value = "Data added"
        .Range("E1").Value = NewRow
        .Activate
        .Range("B3").Select
    End With
    MsgBox "Data added row " & NewRow, vbOKOnly, "Transfer Data"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: A little wrinkle: B38 on the source sheet is not included in the transfer...

Comment: Thank you that looks interesting. B38 is a heading on the pages where the new data is entered and also where the LOOKUP's are used and does not need to be transfered, the comment is there because the new row to cell no. relationship changes after it. Is there a way to use the NewRow value to update the listfillrange and listrows properties of both ComboBox1 and ComboBox2 when data is transfered by this macro?

Comment: @Keith How are they set at present ? `= "'" & name & "'!" & range.address` is usual way. Is the source range a table ?

Comment: listfillrange is Data!A2:A16, I have not defined it in the name manager yet and it is the first column of a data table. listrows is 16, the same as the newrow integer in my macro which is used to tell the macro which row to put the data in. I am doing this work as a volunteer and it is for creating food labels for the meals that we give away. here in the UK we must label it with all ingredients and highlight allergens. The above macro is used to add new recipes to the data table.

Comment: @Keith see update - added `ComboBox1.RowSource = "'" & .Name & "'!A2:A" & NewRow`

Comment: @CDP1802 I have pasted in the above code with a couple of additions as I have extended the number of rows and added another heading, I also added ComboBox2.RowSource etc. When I run the macro I get a compile error "Variable not defined" for ComboBox1 and I'd guess that would be the same for ComboBox2.

Comment: @Keith Add the code name for the sheet where the combobox is located and `ListFillRange` instead of `RowSource` ( that is for comboboxes on user forms) ie `Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "'" & .Name & "'!A2:A" & NewRow`

Comment: Have also tried the code as posted above but I have commented out the Next and ComboBox1 lines. I'm getting another compile error "End with without With"

Comment: @CDP1802 Have added the sheet number and I'm getting a new compile error "Next without For".

Comment: Code is 'With Sheets("Data")
        For i = 1 To 35
           .Cells(NewRow, i) = arData(i, 1)
        Next
        'Range("B38") is a heading
        For i = 37 To UBound(arData)
           .Cells(NewRow, i - 1) = arData(i, 1)
        Next
        'Range("B68") is a heading
        For i = 67 To UBound(arData)
           .Cells(NewRow, i - 2) = arData(i, 1)
        
        Next

        Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "'" & .Name & "'!A2:A" & NewRow
        
        Next

        Sheet6.ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "'" & .Name & "'!A2:A" & NewRow

    End With'

Comment: @Keith see update. You have to expand the range B3:B55

Comment: @CDP1802 That worked perfectly, thank you very very much, it will now be so much easier to use for the peeps adding recipes and printing the labels.